# how to factory reset ASR 1001-X

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-asr, asr

So I was setting up/testing this router. While using auto-secure during the auto-configuration. {Router#setup...}

Once I get through auto setup and reloaded. I was not able to login.

I did some reading online which told me that auto-secure feature disables the "admin" username.

You guessed it, I only setup one username called "admin"

My question is there a way to reset or recover, since I don't have other username to log into the router. If not, then how would i do a factory reset of the ASR 1001-x router.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no actual factory reset like there is on a consumer-grade router. You must perform a [password recovery](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr1000/install/guide/asr1routers/asr-1000-series-hig/asr-hig-tbl.html#con_1050057), then you can erase the startup configuration and reload.

See the detailed instruction in the link above to get into enable mode, then you can:

```
erase startup-config
```

After that:

```
reload
```

Do ***not*** save the running configuration when prompted.

Comment: Or once you're in enable mode, `copy start run` and then add a different (non-admin) user.